# Loop through columns in excel and store the values in an array

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel with values in seperate columns like :

```
32.101869|  -90.051255| 32.10194|   -90.051346| 0|      09120030534SMLUO|   136
```

I want to loop through each column ( preferably for loop)  and store the values in an array.
my code looks like this:

```
    For k = 1 To cw
        j = Replace(Split(Columns(k).Address, ":")(0), "$", "")
        v6 = LCase(Trim(Range(j & i).Value))
        Dim DirArray As Variant
        DirArray = LCase(Trim(Range(j & i).Value))
    Next k
```

In the above code cw is the column used range

and after this i need to create another array with a different set of values and then compare both the arrays to find if there are any mismatches

Comment: If `DirArray` is a variant and `R` is a range then `DirArray = R.Value` loads the values into an array with no loop required.

Comment: ^ http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx

Comment: @JohnColeman sorry i'm a noob. can you type show me how the code would like in this case? i want all the values from A1 to A &cw in my array

Answer (score 0):

i would use array list for this task, I don't now what i is in this code but if previous code works than this should also

```
Dim array As ArrayList
Set array = New ArrayList

For k = 1 To cw
     j = Replace(Split(Columns(k).Address, ":")(0), "$", "")
     v6 = LCase(Trim(Range(j & i).Value))
     array.Add LCase(Trim(Range(j & i).Value))
Next k
```